# Removing a node from the ends of a linked list

Tags: c, list, singly-linked-list

I seem to be having an issue with linked lists, specifically removing the tail (edit: and head) of the list.

```
if(nodeTodelete->next == NULL){
    temp = head;
    while(temp->next != nodeTodelete)
        temp = temp->next;
    temp->next = NULL;
    free(nodeTodelete->name);
    free(nodeTodelete);
    return head;
}
```

This is my code. Assume that head points to the head of my function and that, in this scenario, nodeTodelete points to the tail of the function.

The loop deletes the node successfully, but upon returning to the main function the linked list still believes that the now-freed node is still part of the function, resulting in garbage data at the tail of my . The function will then keep returning to this same garbage node and attempt to interpret its data, causing faulty outputs.

I need to know what I should do to ensure that this tail node is no longer considered part of the list.

edit: it turns out that I am also having issues removing the head
here is my code

```
if(head == nodeTodelete){
    temp = head->next;
    free(nodeTodelete->name);
    free(nodeTodelete);
    return temp;
}
```

Assume nodeTodelete will equal the head in this scenario. Please help me figure out what I may be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to free the `next` node in `temp` and set it to `NULL` :

```
if (nodeTodelete->next == NULL) {
    temp = head;
    while(temp->next != nodeTodelete)
        temp = temp->next;
    free(temp->next->name);
    free(temp->next);
    temp->next = NULL;
    return head;
}
```

You can delete the head in a similar way and you must set it to `NULL` :

```
if (head == nodeTodelete) {
    free(head->name);
    free(head);
    head = NULL;
    return head;
}
```

Comment: I replaced the block of code with what I had previously and it still had the same issue. Hmm...

Comment: how are you iterating overt the nodes and getting garbage ? If you do `while(temp->next) temp = temp->next;` you will stop at the last valid node